# PyQt5 ImportError on M2 MacBook Pro

Tags: python, ventura

I'm trying to install a tool with Python 3.11 under macOS Ventura after exchanging my old MacBook Pro (Intel) for a new M2 MacBook Pro.
When trying to start the tool, I encounter this error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/User/environments/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: __ZTVNSt3__13pmr25monotonic_buffer_resourceE 
    Referenced from: <645DDC2C-F655-324A-BE87-40804F3AC471> /Users/User/environments/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
    Expected in:     <54E8FBE1-DF0D-33A2-B8FA-356565C12929> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
```

As far as I know, this is due to PyQt5 not supporting the arm64 architecture of the M2 chip. I tried installing the tool and all dependencies with an emulated x86_64 architecture, but this again leads to a Numpy import error.
I know that PyQt6 supports arm64 but the tool I use explicitly relies on PyQt5 and changing the code to use PyQt6 instead of PyQt5 is not easily doable (it's not my tool and it's a quite a lot of code).

Is there anything I can do to resolve this issue and continue to use PyQt5 or do I have to fully change the code of the tool to use PyQt6 instead?

Comment: Have you tried running the Terminal in Rosetta?

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, that's when I end up with this Numpy error:
`ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there.`